# Powershell Get-Item not working on some directories like AppData while Get-ChildItem does

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Why does `Get-Item` not work on some directories? For example `gi $env:USERPROFILE\AppData` returns "Could not find item", but `ls $env:USERPROFILE\AppData` works fine and can list files?

I want to use `gi` to pass a string to it to turn it into an object that has other members like `LastWriteTime`. If I use `ls` for `Get-ChildItem` I get the children, i.e. files in the directory, but not the directory.

I can work around this by using a filter on the parent like this: `ls -h $env:USERPROFILE | ? {$_.Name -match "AppData"} | select Name,LastWriteTime` - but there has to be a better way and it does not explain why `gi` does not work directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AppData` directory has the hidden attribute set:

```
PS C:\> attrib $env:USERPROFILE\AppData
    H                C:\Users\username\AppData
```

The hidden attribute means that `Get-Item` ignores it by default. The workaround is to use `-Force`:

```
PS C:\> Get-Item $env:USERPROFILE\AppData -Force

    Directory: C:\Users\username

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d--h--       11/25/2019  12:41 PM                AppData
```

Comment: I began to suspect that the hidden attribute could have something to do with this. But why does `gci` not have the same restriction? It seems really strange to me to design `gc` with the hidden restriction then.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` also ignores items in a file system location with the hidden attribute: Observe the difference in output  between `gci $env:USERPROFILE` and `gci $env:USERPROFILE -Force`.